# I cannot connect django with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I created my project and installed postgresql with a user called myprojectuser with password 'secret' and I create my database called myproject, then I configured in my project of django with the username: myprojectuser with password secret, but I was trying to run my migrations but displayed these errors. http://pastebin.com/8wgY0qMJ

How can I fix it?

I changed in my /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
local all postgres md5 and ran sudo servic

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myproject/polls/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Choice(models.Model):
  File "/home/eduardo/django/Code/myproject/polls/models.py", line 11, in Choice
    question = models.Foreignkey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Foreignkey'
```

Comment: Please put the traceback in your question.

Comment: what do you mean with traceback in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
question = models.Foreignkey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Should be:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

(notice `ForeignKey`)